# How to put the manifold structure on $\wedge^2 M$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with an atlas $\{(U,\varphi)\}$, and let $\wedge^2 M$ be the disjoint union of $A^2(T_p M)$, where $T_pM$ is the tangent bundle of $M$ at $p$ and $A^2(T_p M)$ is the vector space of all alternating bilinear forms on $T_pM$.

In the notes I am reading it says we can put the manifold structure on $\wedge^2 M $ in a similar way as for the cotangent bundle.
I learned how it is done for cotangent bundles, but I am not seeing how to construct the atlas for $\wedge^2 M$... Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Denote the canonical projection by $p:\land^2M\to M$, then for each $U$, take $p^{-1}(U)\cong U\times A^2(T_pM)$.

Comment: I think what I don't get is after this bit... I know we can use the coordinate map to get $U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, but I was wondering how do you construct the map from $A^2(T_pM)$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$ analogously as in the cotangent bundle case (as in  the answer here for example  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720289/natural-manifold-structure-on-the-cotangent-bundle)

Comment: You can analogously define it on coordinates $(p, \xi) \mapsto (\varphi(p), \xi(\partial^i_p, \partial^j_p) $ where $(i,j)$ runs  over all indice pairs $i<j$ and $\xi\in A^2(T_pM) $.